# Value substitution while accessing nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is my json object

```
{
  "a1": {
    "b1": {
      "name": "Tim",
      "status": "Completed"
     }
     "c1" {
       "field1": "name",
       "field2": "status"
     }
  }
```

I need to access the value Tim by getting the field key within c1.
For example, I need to get the value of a1.c1.field1 which gives me the value name1 , then I need to access the value tim by a1.b1.(value of a1.c1.field1)
I do not know how to do this. Can someone give the possible ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a1 = 
{
    "b1":
    {
        "name": "Tim",
        "status": "Completed"
    },
    "c1":
    {
        "field1": "name",
        "field2": "status"
    }
};
console.log(a1.b1[a1.c1.field1]);
```

Do fix the error in your json too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a little off, so it's corrected below. This is an example of how to retrieve the value of field1 in the c1 object (in the a1 object)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = {
        "a1":
        {
            "b1":
            {
                "name": "Tim",
                "status": "Completed"
            },
            "c1":
            {
                "field1": "name",
                "field2": "status"
            }
        }
    };


console.log(json.a1.b1.name); // returns Tim
// or
console.log(json["a1"]["b1"]["name"]); // returns Tim

});
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No I need the value tim after getting the value name. (a1.b1.(name)). This value name needs to come from json.a1.c1.field1

Comment: So you're wanting field1: name to be the actual name value (tim)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access using square brackets. With the data you provided,

```
var data = {
        "a1": {
            "b1": {
                "name": "Tim",
                "status": "Completed"
            },
            "c1":{
                "field1": "name",
                "field2": "status"
            }
    }
};
```

You can achieve your requirement by accessing.

```
data.a1.b1[data.a1.c1.field1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to use `a1.c1.field1` as a property accessor using the bracket notation.

```
var obj = {
    "a1": {
        "b1": {
            "name": "Tim",
            "status": "Completed"
        },

        "c1": {
            "field1": "name",
            "field2": "status"
        }
    }
};

console.log(obj.a1.c1.field1); // 'name'
console.log(obj.a1.b1[obj.a1.c1.field1]); // 'Tim'
```

or, more legibly,

```
var key = obj.a1.c1.field1;
var value = obj.a1.b1[key];
console.log(value); // 'Tim'
```